# React: render form with set of fields depended from selected value

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

Here it is example: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-brown-ib4w6

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const MyForm = (props) => {
  return React.Children.map(props.children, (element) => {
    return element && <div>Addon: {element}</div>;
  });
};

const MyComponentA = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <span>Component A-1</span>
      <span>Component A-2</span>
    </>
  );
};

const MyComponentB = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <span>Component B-1</span>
      <span>Component B-2</span>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [type, setType] = React.useState("a");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setType(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyForm>
        <select onChange={handleChange}>
          <option name="A" value="a">
            A
          </option>
          <option name="B" value="b">
            B
          </option>
        </select>
        <span>Text1</span>
        <span>Text2</span>
        {type === "a" && <MyComponentA />}
        {type === "b" && <MyComponentB />}
      </MyForm>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There is form that adds some wrapper on every its child. And there is select field that modifies subset of the rendered form fields. MyComponents are aimed to group those changed parts. But that breaks final Mycomponents children as part of MyForm. Consider that MyForm is third-party code and can't be changed. How to properly organize such code, reach proper rendering and at the same time keep groups of the fields?

Aim is to get:

```
Addon: Text1
Addon: Text2
Addon: Component A-1
Addon: Component A-2
```

rather than:

```
Addon: Text1
Addon: Text2
Addon: Component A-1Component A-2
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is MyForm  is only looping through it's direct children and wrapping them in the AddOn div. In your case the direct child is the MyComponentA and MyComponentB. They're children are not direct children of MyForm so the entire component is wrapped in the AddOn div.

You can change those from components to simple arrays of elements like so

Change

```
const MyComponentA = (props) => {
   return (
    <>
      <span>Component A-1</span>
      <span>Component A-2</span>
   </>
  );
};
```

To

```
const MyComponentB = [<span>Component B-1</span>, <span>Component B-2</span>];
```

Then when rendering  them in app simply pass in that value (not as a react component)

Change

```
 {type === "a" && <MyComponentA />}
 {type === "b" && <MyComponentB />}
```

To

```
 {type === "a" && MyComponentA}
 {type === "b" && MyComponentB}
```

Hope this was helpful

Comment: Thank you. I considered this obvious solution, But I am thinking there is more better and common approaches here. I mean implementation when part of form fields are changed in dependency from dropdown selector.